# Speed up .htaccess https redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am using the following in my .htaccess file to redirect all users to the https version of the site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In analytics I am seeing its taking up to 2 seconds to carry out this redirect on load.

I have searched around a bit but other types of redirect aren't working or taking longer.

Can anyone tell me if there is a faster way to achieve this?